# Nome de artigo nao deixa introduzir

Tags: c

Quero introduzir o nome do artigo só que ele não deixa, já fiz da mesma forma o scanf igual ao do nome do fornecedor mas não deixa introduzir igual

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char nome[50];// Recebe o nome do Fornecedor
char morada[100];// Recebe a morada do Fornecedor
char cdpst[20];// Recebe o código postal(CTT) do Fornecedor
long int numfisc;// Numero Fiscal do Fornecedor
long int numide;// Numero Identificação do Fornecedor
char artigo[30];// Recebe o nome do Fornecedor
int qtd;// Quantidade do artigo

printf("Introduza o nome do fornecedor:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s",nome);// Lê várias palavras do nome
getchar();//A função getchar() lê um caracter e retorna um inteiro
printf("Introduza a morada:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s",morada);// Lê várias palavras da morada
getchar();//A função getchar() lê um caracter e retorna um inteiro
printf("Introduza código postal:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s",cdpst);
getchar();//A função getchar() lê um caracter e retorna um inteiro
printf("Introduza o seu  numero fiscal:\n");
scanf("%d",&numfisc);
printf("Introduza o numero de fornercedor:\n");
scanf("%ld",&numide); 
printf("Introduza o nome do artigo:\n");
scanf("s",&artigo);
printf("Introduza quantidade entregue do artigo:\n");
scanf("%d",&qtd);
//printf("o fornecedor %s\ncom morada em %s\ncom o código postal %s\ncom o Nº Fiscal %ld\ne o Nº de Fornecedor %ld\nentregou %d unidades\ndo artigo %s",nome,morada,cdpst,numfisc,numide,qtd,artigo);

FILE * fp = fopen("Report Fornecedor.txt", "w+");
if (!fp) {
perror(strerror(errno)); // inclua os headers  string.h  e  errno.h
return EXIT_FAILURE; // inclua stdlib.h
}
{
fprintf(fp,"o fornecedor %s\ncom morada em %s\ncom o codigo postal %s\ncom o Nº Fiscal %ld\ne o Nº de Fornecedor %ld\nentregou %d unidades\ndo artigo %s",nome,morada,cdpst,numfisc,numide,qtd,artigo);
}
fclose(fp);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);             
}
```

A saida do programa é a seguinte:

```
Introduza o nome do fornecedor:
Pecol
Introduza a morada:
Rua da Estrela 25
Introduza código postal:
6000-555
Introduza o seu  numero fiscal:
25555555
Introduza o numero de fornercedor:
1
Introduza o nome do artigo:
Introduza quantidade entregue do artigo:
1000
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema está aqui:

```
scanf("s",&artigo);
```

o que você queria era isso:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", artigo);
```

Comment: Depois de que grupo?

Comment: tenho, fiz este scanf("%[^\n]s", artigo); e continua a não dar, tenho assim para o nome como tenho no código e para este deu certo só para o artigo é que não está a dar

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É sem o s mesmo.

Comment: Fica então como ? já tirei o s e continua a não dar